# Weierstrass's elliptic function-type zeta function

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions, elliptic-functions

What is known about the following Weierstrass's elliptic function-type zeta function

$\sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{(z+m+n\tau)^s}$,

for $z \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{Z} + \tau \mathbb{Z}$ and $\Re s > 2$?

Specifically, is there a meromorphic/analytic continuation to all s and what is analytic/branch-cut structure in z? Does it have a name? A reference would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't think that this can even be well-defined when $s$ is not an integer because the individual terms are not single valued away from the puncture.  Do you have some reason to believe that these ambiguities cancel out?

Comment: You might be thinking to generalize the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) along with [Eisenstein series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series).